# Trouble joining 3 tables (getting not unique table/alias)

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am trying to complete my first successful join but just can't make it work.

Here are my 3 table name and columns:

STORE   columns: id (primary), name, type, country
BANKING  columns:  id, currency
STORE_BANKING (an intermediary table) columns: store_id, banking_id

I have a simple html search form where users can search for results of stores matching results for currency and/or country.

I am getting the error: Not unique table/alias: 'store'

Perhaps my Store_banking syntax is not ok? maybe store_banking.id should be store_banking_id?

Or perhaps I am not using the correct type of join?

```
 $query = "(
 SELECT * 
 FROM store 
 LEFT JOIN store ON banking.id=store.id
 LEFT JOIN banking ON store_banking.id = banking.id
 WHERE ('$type' IS NULL OR '$type' = '' OR type = '$type')
 AND ('$currency' IS NULL OR '$currency' = '' OR currency = '$currency') AND 
('$country' IS NULL OR '$country' = '' OR country = '$country')order by
 name)";
```

So lets say some searches for stores where the country is "any" and the currency is Japanese Yen. The yen value is stored in the table "Banking" so I need the query to check that table and include all stores in the results that match Japanese Yen as the currency. The other values like name and type and country are all in the Stores table so that's easier.

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  The table aliases are all over the place and the table names are different from what is in the question.

Comment: Your "FROM" line has a typo, it should simply read `FROM store_banking`

Comment: I don't see the columns (type, country,...) in your schema!

Comment: type and country are in the STORE table.

Comment: i wish it could just be one table, but the currencies are broken out into the banking table so I can't get the search code to also return results if someone chooses a currency type

Comment: I answered it below, since banking is not a field in your schema I replaced it by currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to search for Currecy, Country and type. Here is the query:

```
 SELECT * FROM Store
            LEFT JOIN STORE_BANKING SB ON Store.id=SB.store_id
            LEFT JOIN banking B ON  SB.banking_id = B.id
            WHERE 
              ('$type' IS NULL OR '$type' = '' OR Store.type = '$type')
            AND 
              ('$country' IS NULL OR '$country' = '' OR Store.country = '$country')
            And
              ('$currency' IS NULL OR '$currency' = '' OR B.currency= '$currency')
           Order by Store.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to join on the same table `store` without giving the one declaration an alias.

Your base query should read: (based on assumption that casino was a copy paste typo and the $banking is supposed to refer to the currency)

```
SELECT * 
 FROM store_banking 
 LEFT JOIN store ON store_banking.store_id=store.id
 LEFT JOIN banking ON store_banking.banking_id = banking.id
 WHERE ('$type' IS NULL OR '$type' = '' OR type = '$type')
 AND ('$banking' IS NULL OR '$banking' = '' OR banking.currency = '$banking') AND 
('$country' IS NULL OR '$country' = '' OR country = '$country') order by
 store.name
```

Comment: good catch on the "casino" copy paste error. I did correct that just before I successfully implemented the first answer I saw above.